# how to write a query1

Tags: mysql, sql

how do i get a query for making  productID, productName
categoryName only the active one's
discontinued = false))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBAsO.png)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, a boolean field is a bit field, so `1 = true`, `0 = false`

```
SELECT productID, productName categoryName FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE discontinued = 0
```